# What is a system_program in anchor?

Tags: anchor, rust, systemprogram

While defining my accounts' structures I encountered this error:

> a non-optional init constraint requires a non-optional system_program
> field to exist in the account validation struct. Use the Program type
> to add the system_program field to your validation struct.

Can someone explain to me that what is a `system_program`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system_program is the program that owns all normal wallet accounts and you also need it to create new accounts. So whenever you create a new account you need to call the system_program to allocate space for them.

When you use init for an anchor account this will internally also do a cpi (cross program invocation) to the system program to create that account. That is why you need to add it whenever you use init or init_if_needed.

On solana you always need to add all accounts that are touched by a transaction. This is so that solana can parallelize the execution

There is btw a limit of 10kb in size for accounts that are created like that. The maximum account size is 10mb though.

Comment: Are system programs native programs?

Comment: The system program is a native program, yes. Here its its address: https://explorer.solana.com/address/11111111111111111111111111111111